# Multiple select query in node js

Tags: node.js, pug

Hello Guys i am newbie in node js, i have a jade framerwork where i have two html options in which i have to get the data from different different sql, If i am doing it with one sql and one html option the everything went fine but as soon as i perform multiple sql it gives me Type Error my js code is:

```
    exports.Questions = function (req, res) {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodeutility',
    multipleStatements: true
});
//res.render('Subcategory', { title: 'Subcategory', year: new Date().getFullYear(), message: 'Your Subcategory page' });
con.connect();
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM mst_category';
con.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('Questions', { title: 'Users', rows: rows });
    res.end;

});
var sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM mst_subcategory';
con.query(sql1, function (err, rows1, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('Questions', { title: 'Users', rows1: rows1 });
    res.end;

});
 con.end();
 };
```

and my jade code is this:

```
            div.form-group
            label(for='name') Select Category:
            select#catname.form-control(name='catname')
                each item in rows
                    option(value=item.id) #{item.Name}
            div.form-group
            label(for='name') Select Sub-Category:
            select#subname.form-control(name='subname')
                each item1 in rows1
                    option(value=item1.id) #{item1.Name}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to do the second query in the callback function of the first.

```
exports.Questions = function(req, res) {
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'nodeutility',
        multipleStatements: true
    });

    con.connect();

    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM mst_category';
    con.query(sql, function(err, rows, fields) {

        if (err) throw err;

        var sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM mst_subcategory';
        con.query(sql1, function(err, rows1, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('Questions', { title: 'Users', rows: rows, rows1: rows1 });
        });

        con.end();

    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks it helps a lot to understand the functionality

Comment: i want to know that if i want to fetch the subcategories based on categories than what's the approach of this?

Comment: Cool, i'm glad it helped. From first query you get rows so you need to extract some identificator of subcategories and add `WHERE <identificator> IN (<subcategories>)` to your `sql1` query .

Comment: can u elaborate more?

Comment: Well i do not know what your *mst_category* table look like and same goes for *mst_subcategory*.

Comment: there is category_id in category table which is foreign key in Subcategory table

Comment: So use query like this to only get sub categories for certain categories `var sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM mst_subcategory WHERE <foreign-key-collumn-name> IN ('category_id1', 'category_id2',...,'category_idX')';`

Comment: ('category_id1', 'category_id2',...,'category_idX')'; whats this means?

Answer (score 2):

this  might help :

```
var mysql = require('mysql')

exports.Questions = function (req, res) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'nodeutility',
        multipleStatements: true
    });

    connection.connect();

    var sql = 'SELECT * FROM mst_category';
    var sql1 = 'SELECT * FROM mst_subcategory';

    connection.query(sql, function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query(sql1, function (err, rows1, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('Questions', { title: 'Users', rows: rows ,rows1: rows1 });
            res.end;
            connection.end();

        });
    });
 };
```